# What are the solutions of $x^3 = 9$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

One of the solutions is $3^{2/3}$. However, I am stuck in obtaining the other solutions. But I am sure that the solutions are imaginary numbers. Give explanation please.

Comment: Are you sure about your equation? Because the equation $x=9^{1/3}$ admits one solution since you prescribe the value of $x$...$9^{1/3}=(3^2)^{1/3}=3^{2/3}$.

Comment: sorry, I made mistake, I have edited it

Comment: See [root of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) and [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula).

Answer (score 1):

They are the solutions of the polynomial equation $$x^3=9$$.

Hence the solutions are $3^{\frac{2}{3}}.1 ,\space 3^{\frac{2}{3}}.\omega, \space 3^{\frac{2}{3}} \omega^2$.

where $\omega=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2} , \omega^2=\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}$

Which is basically $3^{\frac{2}{3}}$ multiplied by the cube roots of unity.

Comment: Note that the equation provided by the OP is the one he's trying to find the roots for. You have provided the equation for which his equation is one of its roots.

Comment: You're correct.. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

as complex numbers, there are three cube roots of $1.$  they are $1, \frac{1 \pm \sqrt 3 i}{2}.$  there cube roots of $9$ are $$3^{2/3}, \frac{3^{2/3}}{2}\left(1 \pm \sqrt 3 i\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

If you write $x$ in polar form $x=Re^{j\theta}$ then your equation can be written as $x^3=R^3e^{j3\theta}=9e^{j2k\pi}$ with solutions $x=3^{2/3}e^{j\frac{2k\pi}{3}}$ and three possible values $3^{2/3}$,  $3^{2/3}e^{j2\pi/3}$ and $3^{2/3}e^{-j2\pi/3}$.